# Panel data classification and regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, regression, forecasting

I am very new to time series/panel/longituginal data. From my understanding Panel data = multi-object time series and I have some panel data in long format (objects have multiple rows corresponding to different time steps). The objective is to predict/classify if a person is going to leave the job due to factors of the job (hrs worked etc). The data looks something like this:

| person | month | # of hrs worked | Quit | Other Feats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 2 | 30 | 0 |  |
| Mary | 3 | 20 | 0 |  |
| Mary | 4 | 80 | 0 |  |
| John | 1 | 100 | 1 |  |
| John | 2 | 10 | 1 |  |
| John | 3 | 60 | 1 |  |
| John | 4 | 40 | 1 |  |
| John | 5 | 100 | 1 |  |
| Cate | 3 | 11 | 0 |  |
| Cate | 4 | 19 | 0 |  |
| Cate | 5 | 29 | 0 |  |
| Cate | 6 | 14 | 0 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |

Where "Quit" is the y or target variable. I am curious how I can predict using this data if an existing person will quit and if a new person will quit. Can I just feed this into a random forest and expect it to do well? (similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469453/xgboost-classification-of-panel-longitudinal-data-observations)) Do I need to transform it to wide format and keep 1 row per person where all the longitudinal aspects are in the columns? I have tried feeding this into a random forest and it gave a good accuracy and AUC but I am not sure if this is the correct way to solve this problem? I have seen people use RNNs to solve this.

Similarly, what about regressing/forecasting on this data? Say instead of a binary outcome I have dates of when a person quit, what techniques exist to regress on this kind of data? Can I just run a linear regression model on this data? What about pooled OLS or GEEs?

One last question is how is this different from classifying on time-series data instead? They both have a time component but panel data has multiple objects.